# Need help with smoothing sharp edges

Tags: edges, 3d-printing, smooth

I have been looking around the internet for a solution, but nothing seems to work for me. I have got this model that I am going to 3d print, but at the scale that I am printing the edges are too coarse. I have tried playing around with modifiers but nothing seems to be working. The outer edges need to stay sharp. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: edge closeup]

[image: full model (size is 2.2x2.6x0.05 m]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare your topology with some inner edges:

[image]

Give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to have a round shape (increase the subdivision up to what you want):

[image]

As it is too round, give it a *Bevel* modifier (that you put above the *Subdivision Surface*), increase the *Angle* value up to around 80°, set the *Amount* and *Segments* values, it will sharpen the edges. Apply the modifiers:

[image]